# PHPExcel: finding page breaks after when creating worksheet on the fly

Tags: php, excel, printing, phpexcel, page-break

for development, i use PHPExcel (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) for creating a Excel (xlsx) document filled with data from a mysql database. So far this works good.

I want to print this Excel document too, as hardcopy to spread around for people reading it from paper. Printing wont be a problem.

The problem lies in: it's a long document, far more rows then will fit on 1 or 2 pages. The worksheet consists of blocks which i want to keep together, when printed, to be on the same page.

I can use a method to set breaks on a row. That i will be able to get to work. But after finishing putting the data on the sheet, i don't know where the automatically placed page breaks are. There is a function (getBreaks()) on the worksheet, which should provide an array with the breaks, but the returned array remains empty, so i can't find out which blocks go over a break.

Can someone help me?
Should i first save the Excel sheet, then open it again and do my job then?
Excel document is created on a shared hosting webserver. No printing options there i guess, at least not where i can manage them.

Other solution is: put a macro's in that Excel document, and let the macro run (to put the breaks on the right places) and print the Excel sheet. (not my favorite solution as i am honest).

Comment: the breaks returned by the `getBreaks()` call are those page breaks that you have explicitly created; PHPExcel does not (nor ever will it) automagically identify possible breaks for you

Comment: ok, that is clear.

But in the Excel application of Office itself, when you do a print preview, and close that preview, you do see the page break lines (blue stripes). These lines aren't comming back from getBreaks()?

How can i then fill a A4 paper size optimal? Keeping sudden rows together? Or detecting that some rows (for example the lower 4 of 8 which need to be on 1 page) are on the next page, so i should put a page break before the first of the 8 rows?

Comment: PHPExcel simply doesn't provide that option at all; I've no idea how I even could implement it.... but it's not information that is accessible from the file, even after displaying it in that print preview in MS Excel

Comment: ok. thought that it was available because it is visible in MS Excel. Other question: can i keep a block/group of rows together on one page?